# Разве так бывает?

Tags: союзы, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение, союзные-слова

*Я не помню такого случая, чтобы отец не вернулся домой из леса.*

Как я понимаю, придаточное здесь определительное, но разве может такое придаточное присоединяться союзом "чтобы", ведь в придаточных этого типа используются только союзные слова.

Comment: Почему не поставили запятую перед _чтобы_? Забыли?

Comment: не помню, чтобы... Перед союзом чтобы всегда ставится запятая.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Бывает. В определительных придаточных используются не только союзные слова.

[**Придаточное предложение**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (Википедия):

> **Придаточные определительные**
>
> Присоединяются с помощью союзных слов: *какой, который, чей, что, где, когда, откуда* и др., а также союзов: *чтобы, как, и тому подобное, словно* и др. Редко с помощью частиц (*ли* и т. д.).

[**Виды придаточных в сложноподчинённом предложении**](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/291-vidypridatochnyhvslognopodchinennyhpredlogeniyah.html) (Видеотьютор по русскому языку):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Информация в разных источниках разная, поэтому смутило.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Спасибо за вопрос и оценку. Да, я тоже просмотрел много, и часто пишут "только". Но даже по примерам можно судить, что далеко не только.

Comment: Александр, а какое значение имеет союз ЧТОБЫ и придаточное в данном случае?  Это уже не только определительное значение, но есть еще дополнительный смысл.

Comment: @Sharon Не знаю, какой доп. смысл вы имеете в виду. Даже если не только определительное значение, но оно же есть?

Comment: Да, есть. Она посмотрела с таким видом, что все замолчали. Это определение + следствие.  А вот какое значение имеет ЧТОБЫ?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
  Я вас не проверяю, просто сама не знаю. У Кустовой союз такой есть, но со значением цели или ирреального следствия, но здесь не похоже. А на что похоже, как вы думаете?

Comment: @Sharon Да я решил не думать об этом :))

Comment: Как же так!) А у кого мне тогда спросить, посоветуйте, пожалуйста)